# How to find the closure of a subset

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

How do I start find the closure of a subset? Let's say I'm given a list, such as
$$A=\left\{\frac12,\frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac24,\frac34,\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45,\cdots\right\}$$
using the standard metric, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Comment: To find the closure of a set $A$, you could start by finding the limit points of the set (call it $A'$).  Then the closure of $A$ is $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$.

Comment: yes, sorry. I did mean 3/5

Comment: Kathryn, if you tell us where you got stuck, we will have a better shot at knowing how to help. In the mean time, I can only suggest that you think about what $A$ really is.

Comment: So this is the collection of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$?

Comment: ok, so I'm looking at the definition of closure and it states if I take an open ball at x, there will be always be a pt in A. So, considering what the set is, it seems that it will always fall in the range (0,1) so is that simply what the closure is?

Comment: Don't forget endpoints.

Comment: so then [0,1] since if i make the neighborhood small enough, it will include 0,1??

Comment: What do you mean that "it" will always fall in that range?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, not quite.

Comment: it, the given set A, will be within [0,1]

Comment: $A$ is a set. It is true that $A\subseteq [0,1]$. You are fairly far from an answer, however.

Comment: if the closure is the set of all closure points of A, why is [0,1] not correct? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Finding the closure is only the first step—proving it is important too. It was not clear from your question to what extent you understood either the concept of closure or the nature of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly concluded that the closure of $A$--which is the set of all rational numbers in the interval $(0,1)$--will be the interval $[0,1],$ but your arguments thus far have not demonstrated this fact.

An effective proof of this will rely on the fact that the rational numbers are dense in the reals. To show that every irrational number in $(0,1)$ is in the closure of $A,$ take an arbitrary irrational $x\in(0,1),$ and an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Show that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ necessarily contains a point of $A$. Hence, since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, then $x$ lies in the closure of $A$. To show that $0$ and $1$ lie in the closure of $A$, we will do something similar. After that, it remains to show that no points of $\Bbb R\setminus[0,1]$ are in the closure of $A$, since they will always have a neighborhood containing no points of $A$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be (at least conceptually) simpler to use adherent points, as the OP's definition suggests, rather than limit points?

Comment: Fair point, David.

Comment: Frankly, I think the traditional introduction to closure in terms of limit points is bizarre. The notion of adherent point is *simpler* than the notion of limit point, and more directly linked to closure, and the concept of closure is (much) more important to topology than the concept of limit point.

Comment: @CameronBuie Is it necessary to show for irrationals considering that the set A consists of only rationals? Or Im sorry, are you using proof by contradiction to show for rationals?

Comment: @Kathryn: It's very straightforward to prove that a set will always be a subset of its closure. (Why? It's easy for the empty set. Suppose $B$ is an arbitrary non-empty set, $x\in B$, and $U$ a neighborhood of $x$. Can you think of a point of $B$ that lies in $U$?) Since the set $A$ consists of all the rationals in the interval $(0,1),$ then we don't need to worry about showing that all those rationals lie in the closure of $A$, because of the general result I mentioned above.